# Auto redirect a user who isn't logged into the Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know how to set functions.php when redirection to login page when a user isn't logged in?
Here's my code which creates some disabilities like no preview on article page etc...

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'swpm_auto_redirect_non_members' );
function swpm_auto_redirect_non_members() {
    if( !is_admin() && !SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in() && !is_page( array( 'membership-login', 'membership-join' )) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/membership-login/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It should work only when website is in service not admin mode.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you wish to redirect your user on login page if user is not logged in. This logic must be work on all front end pages and it must not be impact your admin am i right?

Comment: If my understanding is right than i am having the answer..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You're correct. Sorry for my vague description.

Answer (score -1):

try to make $_SESSION["member],
and make this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["member"]))
{
echo "<script>location='/login.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it creates infinity loop. Tell me where to set.

Comment: to every page that you want to make privacy